# iwlwifi driver issue with ubuntu 20.4

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, iwlwifi

After upgrade ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.4. WIFI driver is broke and bluetooth stopped working.

I tried to download the AX200 driver from Intel official website and copy the firmware to `/lib/firmware` It didn't really help. Installing backport-iwlwifi also didn't work. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
 dmesg | grep iwl

[   12.634574] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'auto_agg' ignored
[   13.094608] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:52:00.0 failed with error -110
[  687.251110] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'auto_agg' ignored
[  687.705909] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:52:00.0 failed with error -110

lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ebb00000-ebb03fff

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0080]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
53:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Genesys Logic, Inc Device [17a0:9755]
```

Only Ethernet is available, WIFI is completely gone.
[image]

Comment: Same problem here. Though it was a fresh 20.04 install. Using Asrock X570 Taichi.

Comment: do you happen to have dual boot windows?

Comment: @ChungLunYuen Hi I am running Linux only. I fixed the issues by removing all the iwlwifi drivers and loaded the new one from Intel. Ubuntu recovery mode seem to fix my bluetooth.

Comment: Same problem here, fresh 20.04 install.

Comment: I have this problem too, except on 20.10 and kernel 5.8.0-44-generic. Things were fine and suddenly they weren't. Same `*-network UNCLAIMED ` and `Wi-Fi 6 AX200`. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm on `ubuntu 20.10` with kernel `5.8.0-44-generic`. My Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 was working fine until one day when something changed and it wasn't.

I got something like this:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.536811] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.570596] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -110
```

and:

```
lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ebb00000-ebb03fff
```

But today when I restarted, it managed to successfully find a version of the firmware that works with my kernel for the AX200, it's: `55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode`.

Which you can find here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html, or specifically in the firmware git tree: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/ where you can see a bunch of them, version 55 included:

```
-rw-r--r--  iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode  1044452 logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode  1096704 logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode  1101228 logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode  1205332 logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode  1219356 logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  iwlwifi-cc-a0-59.ucode  1261280 logstatsplain
```

Hope that helps you and anyone else with this issue. You can manually download that version, put it in your /lib/firmware/ folder and modprobe it (?).

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.621470] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.635643] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.637078] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.637092] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[    2.637096] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.637098] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.637453] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.637481] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    2.812223] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
```